# Match 190 variables to items in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, variables

I have a long list of 190 variables, (they are destination routes).  And I want to match, if any of these variables, exist in the array `arr`.  *(It is necessary for my job to have this many variables).*

For some reason, the code below does not work.  I'm not sure if it's because I have so many variables to check, perhaps the code is not efficient enough?

The route I'm specifically looking for in the array is `"ORY-PSA"`, which is `route72`.

The only time my code works/returns true, is if I remove all the `||` checks, specifically type in the following code:

```
if (arr.indexOf(route72) !== -1) {
    console.log("true");
    return true;
};
```

OR:

```
if (arr.indexOf("ORY-PSA") !== -1) {
    console.log("true");
    return true;
};
```

What's wrong with my original, full length code?

```js
function test(){
    var  route1 = "LGW-MXP";
    var  route2 = "MXP-PMI";
    var  route3 = "MXP-MAH";
    var  route4 = "MXP-IBZ";
    var  route5 = "LGW-FCO";
    var  route6 = "ORY-NAP";
    var  route7 = "MXP-JMK";
    var  route8 = "LGW-PSA";
    var  route9 = "LTN-MXP";
    var route10 = "MXP-CDG";
    var route11 = "MXP-BCN";
    var route12 = "MXP-AMS";
    var route13 = "LGW-VRN";
    var route14 = "LGW-CTA";
    var route15 = "ORY-VCE";
    var route16 = "CDG-VCE";
    var route17 = "LGW-NAP";
    var route18 = "ORY-FCO";
    var route19 = "MXP-TLV";
    var route20 = "BER-VCE";
    var route21 = "BSL-NAP";
    var route22 = "GVA-NAP";
    var route23 = "LGW-VCE";
    var route24 = "CDG-CTA";
    var route25 = "MXP-RAK";
    var route26 = "MXP-TFS";
    var route27 = "BER-NAP";
    var route28 = "BER-CTA";
    var route29 = "FCO-AMS";
    var route30 = "NAP-PMI";
    var route31 = "BER-FCO";
    var route32 = "GVA-BDS";
    var route33 = "BSL-OLB";
    var route34 = "IBZ-NAP";
    var route35 = "BER-OLB";
    var route36 = "MXP-CTA";
    var route37 = "NCE-VCE";
    var route38 = "MXP-CAG";
    var route39 = "MXP-LIS";
    var route40 = "MXP-PMO";
    var route41 = "LGW-BLQ";
    var route42 = "ORY-LIN";
    var route43 = "MXP-MAN";
    var route44 = "MXP-JTR";
    var route45 = "GVA-CTA";
    var route46 = "MXP-CFU";
    var route47 = "NCE-NAP";
    var route48 = "AMS-CTA";
    var route49 = "MXP-OLB";
    var route50 = "MXP-SUF";
    var route51 = "BSL-CTA";
    var route52 = "NAP-CFU";
    var route53 = "GVA-OLB";
    var route54 = "LGW-OLB";
    var route55 = "NAP-BCN";
    var route56 = "LTN-CTA";
    var route57 = "MXP-AGP";
    var route58 = "MAN-NAP";
    var route59 = "AMS-LIN";
    var route60 = "GVA-FCO";
    var route61 = "VCE-OLB";
    var route62 = "LGW-LIN";
    var route63 = "LGW-PMO";
    var route64 = "MXP-HER";
    var route65 = "MXP-ATH";
    var route66 = "MXP-LUX";
    var route67 = "MXP-PRG";
    var route68 = "AMS-OLB";
    var route69 = "MXP-EDI";
    var route70 = "BSL-FCO";
    var route71 = "MXP-BDS";
    var route72 = "ORY-PSA";
    var route73 = "MXP-BRI";
    var route74 = "LYS-FCO";
    var route75 = "CDG-LIN";
    var route76 = "NAP-AMS";
    var route77 = "BER-MXP";
    var route78 = "GVA-CAG";
    var route79 = "MXP-ARN";
    var route80 = "LGW-BRI";
    var route81 = "NAP-MLA";
    var route82 = "ORY-OLB";
    var route83 = "MXP-CPH";
    var route84 = "MAN-PSA";
    var route85 = "LGW-BGY";
    var route86 = "BSL-SUF";
    var route87 = "BSL-BDS";
    var route88 = "MXP-LCA";
    var route89 = "NAP-JMK";
    var route90 = "LYS-CTA";
    var route91 = "GVA-PMO";
    var route92 = "AMS-VCE";
    var route93 = "BSL-CAG";
    var route94 = "LTN-NAP";
    var route95 = "LGW-BDS";
    var route96 = "MXP-KGS";
    var route97 = "BRS-FCO";
    var route98 = "NAP-PMO";
    var route99 = "MAN-OLB";
    var route100 = "NAP-SPU";
    var route101 = "BER-CAG";
    var route102 = "LTN-VCE";
    var route103 = "NAP-CTA";
    var route104 = "MXP-EFL";
    var route105 = "LGW-CAG";
    var route106 = "NAP-OLB";
    var route107 = "BOD-CTA";
    var route108 = "MXP-NAP";
    var route109 = "BRS-PSA";
    var route110 = "EDI-NAP";
    var route111 = "FCO-NCE";
    var route112 = "MXP-RHO";
    var route113 = "MXP-ZTH";
    var route114 = "MAN-VCE";
    var route115 = "NAP-DBV";
    var route116 = "NCE-OLB";
    var route117 = "BRS-VCE";
    var route118 = "NTE-CTA";
    var route119 = "GVA-SUF";
    var route120 = "ORY-CAG";
    var route121 = "NAP-MAH";
    var route122 = "MXP-ACE";
    var route123 = "LTN-PSA";
    var route124 = "BRS-CTA";
    var route125 = "BRS-OLB";
    var route126 = "MXP-BOD";
    var route127 = "BSL-PMO";
    var route128 = "MXP-SSH";
    var route129 = "NAP-LYS";
    var route130 = "MXP-AHO";
    var route131 = "MXP-MUC";
    var route132 = "VCE-JMK";
    var route133 = "NAP-TLV";
    var route134 = "NAP-PRG";
    var route135 = "MXP-FUE";
    var route136 = "BRS-NAP";
    var route137 = "OLB-BGY";
    var route138 = "NAP-RHO";
    var route139 = "IBZ-VCE";
    var route140 = "MXP-SPU";
    var route141 = "NAP-ATH";
    var route142 = "MXP-CHQ";
    var route143 = "ORY-PMO";
    var route144 = "LTN-PMO";
    var route145 = "AMS-PMO";
    var route146 = "MXP-NTE";
    var route147 = "BOD-OLB";
    var route148 = "VCE-RHO";
    var route149 = "BSL-AHO";
    var route150 = "LTN-OLB";
    var route151 = "MXP-ZAD";
    var route152 = "LYS-OLB";
    var route153 = "LYS-PMO";
    var route154 = "LYS-VCE";
    var route155 = "FCO-NTE";
    var route156 = "VCE-EDI";
    var route157 = "NAP-HRG";
    var route158 = "LGW-TRN";
    var route159 = "BER-LIN";
    var route160 = "MXP-PVK";
    var route161 = "ORY-BDS";
    var route162 = "MXP-MLA";
    var route163 = "AMS-VRN";
    var route164 = "NAP-CAG";
    var route165 = "CDG-OLB";
    var route166 = "AMS-BGY";
    var route167 = "CDG-BGY";
    var route168 = "TLS-OLB";
    var route169 = "GVA-AHO";
    var route170 = "MAN-TRN";
    var route171 = "MXP-BIO";
    var route172 = "NAP-SSH";
    var route173 = "NTE-OLB";
    var route174 = "MAN-FCO";
    var route175 = "NTE-BRI";
    var route176 = "NAP-TFS";
    var route177 = "BRS-TRN";
    var route178 = "GLA-VCE";
    var route179 = "NCE-CTA";
    var route180 = "BRS-MXP";
    var route181 = "OLB-TRN";
    var route182 = "MXP-HRG";
    var route183 = "OLB-BRI";
    var route184 = "MXP-FAO";
    var route185 = "MXP-RMF";
    var route186 = "BCN-LIN";
    var route187 = "BSL-BRI";
    var route188 = "MAN-CTA";
    var route189 = "MXP-OPO";
    var route190 = "MXP-AQJ";

    var arr = ['ORY-PSA', 'ORY-PSA', 'ORY-PSA', 'ORY-PSA', 'PSA-ORY', 'PSA-ORY', 'PSA-ORY', 'PSA-ORY']
    
    console.log("arr", arr);
    if (arr.indexOf(route1 || route2 || route3 || route4 || route5 || route6 || route7 || route8 || route9 || route10 || route11 || route12 || route13 || route14 || route15 || route16 || route17 || route18 || route19 || route20 || route21 || route22 || route23 || route24 || route25 || route26 || route27 || route28 || route29 || route30 || route31 || route32 || route33 || route34 || route35 || route36 || route37 || route38 || route39 || route40 || route41 || route42 || route43 || route44 || route45 || route46 || route47 || route48 || route49 || route50 || route51 || route52 || route53 || route54 || route55 || route56 || route57 || route58 || route59 || route60 || route61 || route62 || route63 || route64 || route65 || route66 || route67 || route68 || route69 || route70 || route71 || route72 || route73 || route74 || route75 || route76 || route77 || route78 || route79 || route80 || route81 || route82 || route83 || route84 || route85 || route86 || route87 || route88 || route89 || route90 || route91 || route92 || route93 || route94 || route95 || route96 || route97 || route98 || route99 || route100 || route101 || route102 || route103 || route104 || route105 || route106 || route107 || route108 || route109 || route110 || route111 || route112 || route113 || route114 || route115 || route116 || route117 || route118 || route119 || route120 || route121 || route122 || route123 || route124 || route125 || route126 || route127 || route128 || route129 || route130 || route131 || route132 || route133 || route134 || route135 || route136 || route137 || route138 || route139 || route140 || route141 || route142 || route143 || route144 || route145 || route146 || route147 || route148 || route149 || route150 || route151 || route152 || route153 || route154 || route155 || route156 || route157 || route158 || route159 || route160 || route161 || route162 || route163 || route164 || route165 || route166 || route167 || route168 || route169 || route170 || route171 || route172 || route173 || route174 || route175 || route176 || route177 || route178 || route179 || route180 || route181 || route182 || route183 || route184 || route185 || route186 || route187 || route188 || route189 || route190) !== -1) {
        console.log("true");
        return true;
    };
};

test();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you went wrong: the result of `v1 || v2 || v3`  is just a **single value**, for reference see [MDN Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#using_or) especially the examples that use strings on either side. And that **single value** then gets fed into `indexOf()`.

The best way to use this kind of data is *through arrays*, so let's create an array and use that, in this case with the array [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function:

```js
function test(){
    var  route1 = "LGW-MXP";
    var  route2 = "MXP-PMI";
    var  route3 = "MXP-MAH";
    var  route4 = "MXP-IBZ";
    var  route5 = "LGW-FCO";
    var  route6 = "ORY-NAP";
    var  route7 = "MXP-JMK";
    var  route8 = "LGW-PSA";
    var  route9 = "LTN-MXP";
    var route10 = "MXP-CDG";
    var route11 = "MXP-BCN";
    var route12 = "MXP-AMS";
    var route13 = "LGW-VRN";
    var route14 = "LGW-CTA";
    var route15 = "ORY-VCE";
    var route16 = "CDG-VCE";
    var route17 = "LGW-NAP";
    var route18 = "ORY-FCO";
    var route19 = "MXP-TLV";
    var route20 = "BER-VCE";
    var route21 = "BSL-NAP";
    var route22 = "GVA-NAP";
    var route23 = "LGW-VCE";
    var route24 = "CDG-CTA";
    var route25 = "MXP-RAK";
    var route26 = "MXP-TFS";
    var route27 = "BER-NAP";
    var route28 = "BER-CTA";
    var route29 = "FCO-AMS";
    var route30 = "NAP-PMI";
    var route31 = "BER-FCO";
    var route32 = "GVA-BDS";
    var route33 = "BSL-OLB";
    var route34 = "IBZ-NAP";
    var route35 = "BER-OLB";
    var route36 = "MXP-CTA";
    var route37 = "NCE-VCE";
    var route38 = "MXP-CAG";
    var route39 = "MXP-LIS";
    var route40 = "MXP-PMO";
    var route41 = "LGW-BLQ";
    var route42 = "ORY-LIN";
    var route43 = "MXP-MAN";
    var route44 = "MXP-JTR";
    var route45 = "GVA-CTA";
    var route46 = "MXP-CFU";
    var route47 = "NCE-NAP";
    var route48 = "AMS-CTA";
    var route49 = "MXP-OLB";
    var route50 = "MXP-SUF";
    var route51 = "BSL-CTA";
    var route52 = "NAP-CFU";
    var route53 = "GVA-OLB";
    var route54 = "LGW-OLB";
    var route55 = "NAP-BCN";
    var route56 = "LTN-CTA";
    var route57 = "MXP-AGP";
    var route58 = "MAN-NAP";
    var route59 = "AMS-LIN";
    var route60 = "GVA-FCO";
    var route61 = "VCE-OLB";
    var route62 = "LGW-LIN";
    var route63 = "LGW-PMO";
    var route64 = "MXP-HER";
    var route65 = "MXP-ATH";
    var route66 = "MXP-LUX";
    var route67 = "MXP-PRG";
    var route68 = "AMS-OLB";
    var route69 = "MXP-EDI";
    var route70 = "BSL-FCO";
    var route71 = "MXP-BDS";
    var route72 = "ORY-PSA";
    var route73 = "MXP-BRI";
    var route74 = "LYS-FCO";
    var route75 = "CDG-LIN";
    var route76 = "NAP-AMS";
    var route77 = "BER-MXP";
    var route78 = "GVA-CAG";
    var route79 = "MXP-ARN";
    var route80 = "LGW-BRI";
    var route81 = "NAP-MLA";
    var route82 = "ORY-OLB";
    var route83 = "MXP-CPH";
    var route84 = "MAN-PSA";
    var route85 = "LGW-BGY";
    var route86 = "BSL-SUF";
    var route87 = "BSL-BDS";
    var route88 = "MXP-LCA";
    var route89 = "NAP-JMK";
    var route90 = "LYS-CTA";
    var route91 = "GVA-PMO";
    var route92 = "AMS-VCE";
    var route93 = "BSL-CAG";
    var route94 = "LTN-NAP";
    var route95 = "LGW-BDS";
    var route96 = "MXP-KGS";
    var route97 = "BRS-FCO";
    var route98 = "NAP-PMO";
    var route99 = "MAN-OLB";
    var route100 = "NAP-SPU";
    var route101 = "BER-CAG";
    var route102 = "LTN-VCE";
    var route103 = "NAP-CTA";
    var route104 = "MXP-EFL";
    var route105 = "LGW-CAG";
    var route106 = "NAP-OLB";
    var route107 = "BOD-CTA";
    var route108 = "MXP-NAP";
    var route109 = "BRS-PSA";
    var route110 = "EDI-NAP";
    var route111 = "FCO-NCE";
    var route112 = "MXP-RHO";
    var route113 = "MXP-ZTH";
    var route114 = "MAN-VCE";
    var route115 = "NAP-DBV";
    var route116 = "NCE-OLB";
    var route117 = "BRS-VCE";
    var route118 = "NTE-CTA";
    var route119 = "GVA-SUF";
    var route120 = "ORY-CAG";
    var route121 = "NAP-MAH";
    var route122 = "MXP-ACE";
    var route123 = "LTN-PSA";
    var route124 = "BRS-CTA";
    var route125 = "BRS-OLB";
    var route126 = "MXP-BOD";
    var route127 = "BSL-PMO";
    var route128 = "MXP-SSH";
    var route129 = "NAP-LYS";
    var route130 = "MXP-AHO";
    var route131 = "MXP-MUC";
    var route132 = "VCE-JMK";
    var route133 = "NAP-TLV";
    var route134 = "NAP-PRG";
    var route135 = "MXP-FUE";
    var route136 = "BRS-NAP";
    var route137 = "OLB-BGY";
    var route138 = "NAP-RHO";
    var route139 = "IBZ-VCE";
    var route140 = "MXP-SPU";
    var route141 = "NAP-ATH";
    var route142 = "MXP-CHQ";
    var route143 = "ORY-PMO";
    var route144 = "LTN-PMO";
    var route145 = "AMS-PMO";
    var route146 = "MXP-NTE";
    var route147 = "BOD-OLB";
    var route148 = "VCE-RHO";
    var route149 = "BSL-AHO";
    var route150 = "LTN-OLB";
    var route151 = "MXP-ZAD";
    var route152 = "LYS-OLB";
    var route153 = "LYS-PMO";
    var route154 = "LYS-VCE";
    var route155 = "FCO-NTE";
    var route156 = "VCE-EDI";
    var route157 = "NAP-HRG";
    var route158 = "LGW-TRN";
    var route159 = "BER-LIN";
    var route160 = "MXP-PVK";
    var route161 = "ORY-BDS";
    var route162 = "MXP-MLA";
    var route163 = "AMS-VRN";
    var route164 = "NAP-CAG";
    var route165 = "CDG-OLB";
    var route166 = "AMS-BGY";
    var route167 = "CDG-BGY";
    var route168 = "TLS-OLB";
    var route169 = "GVA-AHO";
    var route170 = "MAN-TRN";
    var route171 = "MXP-BIO";
    var route172 = "NAP-SSH";
    var route173 = "NTE-OLB";
    var route174 = "MAN-FCO";
    var route175 = "NTE-BRI";
    var route176 = "NAP-TFS";
    var route177 = "BRS-TRN";
    var route178 = "GLA-VCE";
    var route179 = "NCE-CTA";
    var route180 = "BRS-MXP";
    var route181 = "OLB-TRN";
    var route182 = "MXP-HRG";
    var route183 = "OLB-BRI";
    var route184 = "MXP-FAO";
    var route185 = "MXP-RMF";
    var route186 = "BCN-LIN";
    var route187 = "BSL-BRI";
    var route188 = "MAN-CTA";
    var route189 = "MXP-OPO";
    var route190 = "MXP-AQJ";

    var arr = ['ORY-PSA', 'ORY-PSA', 'ORY-PSA', 'ORY-PSA', 'PSA-ORY', 'PSA-ORY', 'PSA-ORY', 'PSA-ORY']
    
    var routes = [route1, route2, route3, route4, route5, route6, route7, route8, route9, route10, route11, route12, route13, route14, route15, route16, route17, route18, route19, route20, route21, route22, route23, route24, route25, route26, route27, route28, route29, route30, route31, route32, route33, route34, route35, route36, route37, route38, route39, route40, route41, route42, route43, route44, route45, route46, route47, route48, route49, route50, route51, route52, route53, route54, route55, route56, route57, route58, route59, route60, route61, route62, route63, route64, route65, route66, route67, route68, route69, route70, route71, route72, route73, route74, route75, route76, route77, route78, route79, route80, route81, route82, route83, route84, route85, route86, route87, route88, route89, route90, route91, route92, route93, route94, route95, route96, route97, route98, route99, route100, route101, route102, route103, route104, route105, route106, route107, route108, route109, route110, route111, route112, route113, route114, route115, route116, route117, route118, route119, route120, route121, route122, route123, route124, route125, route126, route127, route128, route129, route130, route131, route132, route133, route134, route135, route136, route137, route138, route139, route140, route141, route142, route143, route144, route145, route146, route147, route148, route149, route150, route151, route152, route153, route154, route155, route156, route157, route158, route159, route160, route161, route162, route163, route164, route165, route166, route167, route168, route169, route170, route171, route172, route173, route174, route175, route176, route177, route178, route179, route180, route181, route182, route183, route184, route185, route186, route187, route188, route189, route190];
    
    if (routes.some(r => arr.indexOf(r) !== -1)) {
        console.log("true");
        return true;
    };
};

test();
```

---

Or we can (even better IMO) use `includes` instead of `indexOf`, because we don't actually care about the *`index`* value (expand snippet to see):

```js
function test(){
    var  route1 = "LGW-MXP";
    var  route2 = "MXP-PMI";
    var  route3 = "MXP-MAH";
    var  route4 = "MXP-IBZ";
    var  route5 = "LGW-FCO";
    var  route6 = "ORY-NAP";
    var  route7 = "MXP-JMK";
    var  route8 = "LGW-PSA";
    var  route9 = "LTN-MXP";
    var route10 = "MXP-CDG";
    var route11 = "MXP-BCN";
    var route12 = "MXP-AMS";
    var route13 = "LGW-VRN";
    var route14 = "LGW-CTA";
    var route15 = "ORY-VCE";
    var route16 = "CDG-VCE";
    var route17 = "LGW-NAP";
    var route18 = "ORY-FCO";
    var route19 = "MXP-TLV";
    var route20 = "BER-VCE";
    var route21 = "BSL-NAP";
    var route22 = "GVA-NAP";
    var route23 = "LGW-VCE";
    var route24 = "CDG-CTA";
    var route25 = "MXP-RAK";
    var route26 = "MXP-TFS";
    var route27 = "BER-NAP";
    var route28 = "BER-CTA";
    var route29 = "FCO-AMS";
    var route30 = "NAP-PMI";
    var route31 = "BER-FCO";
    var route32 = "GVA-BDS";
    var route33 = "BSL-OLB";
    var route34 = "IBZ-NAP";
    var route35 = "BER-OLB";
    var route36 = "MXP-CTA";
    var route37 = "NCE-VCE";
    var route38 = "MXP-CAG";
    var route39 = "MXP-LIS";
    var route40 = "MXP-PMO";
    var route41 = "LGW-BLQ";
    var route42 = "ORY-LIN";
    var route43 = "MXP-MAN";
    var route44 = "MXP-JTR";
    var route45 = "GVA-CTA";
    var route46 = "MXP-CFU";
    var route47 = "NCE-NAP";
    var route48 = "AMS-CTA";
    var route49 = "MXP-OLB";
    var route50 = "MXP-SUF";
    var route51 = "BSL-CTA";
    var route52 = "NAP-CFU";
    var route53 = "GVA-OLB";
    var route54 = "LGW-OLB";
    var route55 = "NAP-BCN";
    var route56 = "LTN-CTA";
    var route57 = "MXP-AGP";
    var route58 = "MAN-NAP";
    var route59 = "AMS-LIN";
    var route60 = "GVA-FCO";
    var route61 = "VCE-OLB";
    var route62 = "LGW-LIN";
    var route63 = "LGW-PMO";
    var route64 = "MXP-HER";
    var route65 = "MXP-ATH";
    var route66 = "MXP-LUX";
    var route67 = "MXP-PRG";
    var route68 = "AMS-OLB";
    var route69 = "MXP-EDI";
    var route70 = "BSL-FCO";
    var route71 = "MXP-BDS";
    var route72 = "ORY-PSA";
    var route73 = "MXP-BRI";
    var route74 = "LYS-FCO";
    var route75 = "CDG-LIN";
    var route76 = "NAP-AMS";
    var route77 = "BER-MXP";
    var route78 = "GVA-CAG";
    var route79 = "MXP-ARN";
    var route80 = "LGW-BRI";
    var route81 = "NAP-MLA";
    var route82 = "ORY-OLB";
    var route83 = "MXP-CPH";
    var route84 = "MAN-PSA";
    var route85 = "LGW-BGY";
    var route86 = "BSL-SUF";
    var route87 = "BSL-BDS";
    var route88 = "MXP-LCA";
    var route89 = "NAP-JMK";
    var route90 = "LYS-CTA";
    var route91 = "GVA-PMO";
    var route92 = "AMS-VCE";
    var route93 = "BSL-CAG";
    var route94 = "LTN-NAP";
    var route95 = "LGW-BDS";
    var route96 = "MXP-KGS";
    var route97 = "BRS-FCO";
    var route98 = "NAP-PMO";
    var route99 = "MAN-OLB";
    var route100 = "NAP-SPU";
    var route101 = "BER-CAG";
    var route102 = "LTN-VCE";
    var route103 = "NAP-CTA";
    var route104 = "MXP-EFL";
    var route105 = "LGW-CAG";
    var route106 = "NAP-OLB";
    var route107 = "BOD-CTA";
    var route108 = "MXP-NAP";
    var route109 = "BRS-PSA";
    var route110 = "EDI-NAP";
    var route111 = "FCO-NCE";
    var route112 = "MXP-RHO";
    var route113 = "MXP-ZTH";
    var route114 = "MAN-VCE";
    var route115 = "NAP-DBV";
    var route116 = "NCE-OLB";
    var route117 = "BRS-VCE";
    var route118 = "NTE-CTA";
    var route119 = "GVA-SUF";
    var route120 = "ORY-CAG";
    var route121 = "NAP-MAH";
    var route122 = "MXP-ACE";
    var route123 = "LTN-PSA";
    var route124 = "BRS-CTA";
    var route125 = "BRS-OLB";
    var route126 = "MXP-BOD";
    var route127 = "BSL-PMO";
    var route128 = "MXP-SSH";
    var route129 = "NAP-LYS";
    var route130 = "MXP-AHO";
    var route131 = "MXP-MUC";
    var route132 = "VCE-JMK";
    var route133 = "NAP-TLV";
    var route134 = "NAP-PRG";
    var route135 = "MXP-FUE";
    var route136 = "BRS-NAP";
    var route137 = "OLB-BGY";
    var route138 = "NAP-RHO";
    var route139 = "IBZ-VCE";
    var route140 = "MXP-SPU";
    var route141 = "NAP-ATH";
    var route142 = "MXP-CHQ";
    var route143 = "ORY-PMO";
    var route144 = "LTN-PMO";
    var route145 = "AMS-PMO";
    var route146 = "MXP-NTE";
    var route147 = "BOD-OLB";
    var route148 = "VCE-RHO";
    var route149 = "BSL-AHO";
    var route150 = "LTN-OLB";
    var route151 = "MXP-ZAD";
    var route152 = "LYS-OLB";
    var route153 = "LYS-PMO";
    var route154 = "LYS-VCE";
    var route155 = "FCO-NTE";
    var route156 = "VCE-EDI";
    var route157 = "NAP-HRG";
    var route158 = "LGW-TRN";
    var route159 = "BER-LIN";
    var route160 = "MXP-PVK";
    var route161 = "ORY-BDS";
    var route162 = "MXP-MLA";
    var route163 = "AMS-VRN";
    var route164 = "NAP-CAG";
    var route165 = "CDG-OLB";
    var route166 = "AMS-BGY";
    var route167 = "CDG-BGY";
    var route168 = "TLS-OLB";
    var route169 = "GVA-AHO";
    var route170 = "MAN-TRN";
    var route171 = "MXP-BIO";
    var route172 = "NAP-SSH";
    var route173 = "NTE-OLB";
    var route174 = "MAN-FCO";
    var route175 = "NTE-BRI";
    var route176 = "NAP-TFS";
    var route177 = "BRS-TRN";
    var route178 = "GLA-VCE";
    var route179 = "NCE-CTA";
    var route180 = "BRS-MXP";
    var route181 = "OLB-TRN";
    var route182 = "MXP-HRG";
    var route183 = "OLB-BRI";
    var route184 = "MXP-FAO";
    var route185 = "MXP-RMF";
    var route186 = "BCN-LIN";
    var route187 = "BSL-BRI";
    var route188 = "MAN-CTA";
    var route189 = "MXP-OPO";
    var route190 = "MXP-AQJ";

    var arr = ['ORY-PSA', 'ORY-PSA', 'ORY-PSA', 'ORY-PSA', 'PSA-ORY', 'PSA-ORY', 'PSA-ORY', 'PSA-ORY']
    
    var routes = [route1, route2, route3, route4, route5, route6, route7, route8, route9, route10, route11, route12, route13, route14, route15, route16, route17, route18, route19, route20, route21, route22, route23, route24, route25, route26, route27, route28, route29, route30, route31, route32, route33, route34, route35, route36, route37, route38, route39, route40, route41, route42, route43, route44, route45, route46, route47, route48, route49, route50, route51, route52, route53, route54, route55, route56, route57, route58, route59, route60, route61, route62, route63, route64, route65, route66, route67, route68, route69, route70, route71, route72, route73, route74, route75, route76, route77, route78, route79, route80, route81, route82, route83, route84, route85, route86, route87, route88, route89, route90, route91, route92, route93, route94, route95, route96, route97, route98, route99, route100, route101, route102, route103, route104, route105, route106, route107, route108, route109, route110, route111, route112, route113, route114, route115, route116, route117, route118, route119, route120, route121, route122, route123, route124, route125, route126, route127, route128, route129, route130, route131, route132, route133, route134, route135, route136, route137, route138, route139, route140, route141, route142, route143, route144, route145, route146, route147, route148, route149, route150, route151, route152, route153, route154, route155, route156, route157, route158, route159, route160, route161, route162, route163, route164, route165, route166, route167, route168, route169, route170, route171, route172, route173, route174, route175, route176, route177, route178, route179, route180, route181, route182, route183, route184, route185, route186, route187, route188, route189, route190];
    
    if (routes.some(r => arr.includes(r))) {
        console.log("true");
        return true;
    };
};

test();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate this explanation.  I always use indexOf to check single values, but never a collection of data.  So really appreciate the breakdown here.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment I can't see a better way then doing it the manual way. If it where possible to add the `routexxx` variables to an array you could make it way more simple.

```js
function test() {
    var route1 = "LGW-MXP";
    var route2 = "MXP-PMI";
    var route3 = "MXP-MAH";
    var route4 = "MXP-IBZ";
    //...
    var route72 = "ORY-PSA";
    //...
    var route188 = "MAN-CTA";
    var route189 = "MXP-OPO";
    var route190 = "MXP-AQJ";

    var arr = ['ORY-PSA', 'ORY-PSA', 'ORY-PSA', 'ORY-PSA', 'PSA-ORY', 'PSA-ORY', 'PSA-ORY', 'PSA-ORY']

    console.log("arr", arr);
    for (let x of arr) {
        if (x == route1 ||
            x == route2 ||
            x == route3 ||
            //...
            x == route72
            //...
            ) {
            console.log("true");
            return true;
        }
    }
};

test();
```

Comment: appreciate the alternative solution, here - thank so much!